# Slow UWP performance

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a problem with slow UWP performance. I know that this topic was discussed a lot of times, but everything is from 2017 or older, and nothing was useful for me. In short, the more times I change application's pages, the more lagging I have.

I tried all combinations: disabling and enabling option Compile with .NET Native tool chain, switching between Debug and Release mode, I wrote application native way and in `Xamarin.Forms` (Android works good what's interesting) but every time I had problem with UWP. The method I use to going to other page:

```
  this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
```

So my question is, if anyone solved problem with lagging, or is maybe other method for switching pages?

Comment: Could you please send us some examples of what your pages do? Your issue sounds like the pages are kept in memory and that causes the performance degradation over multiple navigations.

Comment: As @MartinZikmund mentioned.. you should add some code/examples so that we know what your pages are doing after the navigation happens. It isn't the navigation itself which is degrading the performance but the logic of what the pages do after they are navigated to from other pages which seems to be the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. In my case the problem was in handling my UserControl toolbar - too often refreshing data. I added longer `Task.Delay` to my infinite loop that was refreshing data on toolbar and now everything works fine.